# Python key match between dictionary and nested dictionary and write new value to nested dictionary

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries, one is a standard key/value pair dictionary and the other is a nested OrderedDict with common key names to the standard dictionary, but has empty values.

I am looking for a way to extract the values from the standard key/value dictionary (properties_dict) and drop these values into my nested dictionary (blank_dict) where the keys match.

I've looked into using 'isinstance' to iterate over values which form other lists/dictionaries, but now I'm beginning to wonder if I am going down the wrong path and possibly overcomplicating it.  The other problem I have is one value 'Variant' is in list form, so was looking for a way to pop each value out of the list as it traverses the OrderedDict.

I have added my attempt below.

```
from collections import OrderedDict


def walkdicts(blankdict, propsdict):
    for k, v in blankdict.items():
        for k2, v2 in propsdict.items():
            if k == k2:
                blankdict[k] = v2
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            walkdicts(v, propsdict)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for i in v:
                walkdicts(i[0], propsdict)

    return blankdict


properties_dict = {'A_ID': '2702',
 'Sys': 'MySystem',
 'Namespace': 'SomeNamespace',
 'Vers': '112A',
 'Variant': ['1','2'],
 'SpecID': 'Target1',
 'Seq': '12345',
 'Match': 'ABCDEFG',
 'Time': '200',
 'Case1': 'A',
 'Type': 'Include',
 'MyRef': '1010',
 'Case2': 'B'}


blank_dict =   OrderedDict([('Main', OrderedDict([
                    ('Vers', ''), 
                    ('Namespace', ''), 
                    ('Sys', ''), 
                    ('A_ID', ''),
                    ('Variant', '1'),
                ('Sec1', OrderedDict([
                    ('RequestID', OrderedDict([
                        ('Case1', ''), 
                        ('Case2', '')])), 
                    ('Variant', ''), 
                    ('MyRef', '')])), 
                ('Sec2', OrderedDict([
                    ('UHD', OrderedDict([
                        ('SpecID', ''), 
                        ('Type', ''), 
                        ('AD2W', OrderedDict([
                            ('Time', ''), 
                            ('Match', ''), 
                            ('Seq', '')]))]))]))]))])


new_dict = walkdicts(blank_dict, properties_dict)

print(new_dict)
```

Here's the output Ordered dictionary I was looking for:

```
    new_dict =   OrderedDict([('Main', OrderedDict([
                    ('Vers', '112A'), 
                    ('Namespace', 'SomeNamespace'), 
                    ('Sys', 'MySystem'), 
                    ('A_ID', '2702'),
                    ('Variant', '1'),
                ('Sec1', OrderedDict([
                    ('RequestID', OrderedDict([
                        ('Case1', 'A'), 
                        ('Case2', 'B')])), 
                    ('Variant', '2'), 
                    ('MyRef', '1010')])), 
                ('Sec2', OrderedDict([
                    ('UHD', OrderedDict([
                        ('SpecID', 'Target1'), 
                        ('Type', 'Include'), 
                        ('AD2W', OrderedDict([
                            ('Time', '200'), 
                            ('Match', 'ABCDEFG'), 
                            ('Seq', '12345')]))]))]))]))])
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you share with us the expected result that you're looking for?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question with the expected result

Comment: As @chuckx mentions my nested OrderedDict instances we're missing in the original blank_dict dictionary, I have edited and placed these back in.

Comment: Your nested list of tuples is literally complicated and time consuming to work on it!!! Even if you find a solution for it. In big scale of data. It will destroy your memory performance and even if you had a good resource... Reading this code is very lackble. If this possible. Can you share the main source data that you read the theae data from so we can restructure it.

Comment: You were totally right to switch to dict. But this not seems to be a pythonic dictionary!!!

Comment: @Dr.Xavier [`OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) takes a list of a key/value pairs as arguments to seed the dictionary. After it's been instantiated you interact with it like a normal `dict`. For example, see my answer where I create an empty `OrderedDict` and then populate it using the normal `dict[key] = value` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function which returns a nested `OrderedDict` which matches the structure in `template`, with the values populated by performing lookups in `props`:

```
def populate(template, props, prop_indexes=None):
    if prop_indexes is None:
        prop_indexes = {}
    result = OrderedDict()
    for k, v in template.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            result[k] = populate(v, props, prop_indexes)
            continue
        if k in props.keys():
            if isinstance(props[k], list):
                if k not in prop_indexes:
                    prop_indexes[k] = 0
                index = prop_indexes[k] % len(props[k])
                result[k] = props[k][index]
                prop_indexes[k] += 1
            else:
                result[k] = props[k]
    return result
```

A few notes:

- `prop_indexes` is used to keep track of where we are for each property that's defined as a list of values. Using the modulus (`%`) operator, we can repeatedly cycle through the list if there are more instances in `target` than there are values in the list
- Since `props` is a dictionary, there's no need to loop through it. Instead, simply check if the key exists.
- This could still use some work to gracefully handle edge cases and error conditions, but I just wanted to demonstrate a working approach. A major assumption is that `template` consists only of nested dictionaries.

---

Using the definitions of `blank_dict` (slightly modified by adding an extra `Variant` key, see Note after the output) and `properties_dict` from your example code, here's a small bit of code to  put it all together:

```
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()

print("## blank_dict ##")
pp.pprint(blank_dict)

new_dict = populate_new(blank_dict, properties_dict)

print("## new_dict ##")
pp.pprint(new_dict)
```

And here's the output (`pprint` doesn't really render `OrderedDict` all that pretty, but it gets the job done):

```
## blank_dict ##
OrderedDict([('Main',
              OrderedDict([('Vers', ''),
                           ('Namespace', ''),
                           ('Sys', ''),
                           ('A_ID', ''),
                           ('Variant', ''),
                           ('Sec1',
                            OrderedDict([('RequestID',
                                          OrderedDict([('Case1', ''),
                                                       ('Case2', '')])),
                                         ('Variant', ''),
                                         ('MyRef', '')])),
                           ('Sec2',
                            OrderedDict([('UHD',
                                          OrderedDict([('SpecID', ''),
                                                       ('Type', ''),
                                                       ('Variant', ''),
                                                       ('AD2W',
                                                        OrderedDict([('Time',
                                                                      ''),
                                                                     ('Match',
                                                                      ''),
                                                                     ('Seq',
                                                                      '')]))]))]))]))])
## new_dict ##
OrderedDict([('Main',
              OrderedDict([('Vers', '112A'),
                           ('Namespace', 'SomeNamespace'),
                           ('Sys', 'MySystem'),
                           ('A_ID', '2702'),
                           ('Variant', '1'),
                           ('Sec1',
                            OrderedDict([('RequestID',
                                          OrderedDict([('Case1', 'A'),
                                                       ('Case2', 'B')])),
                                         ('Variant', '2'),
                                         ('MyRef', '1010')])),
                           ('Sec2',
                            OrderedDict([('UHD',
                                          OrderedDict([('SpecID', 'Target1'),
                                                       ('Type', 'Include'),
                                                       ('Variant', '1'),
                                                       ('AD2W',
                                                        OrderedDict([('Time',
                                                                      '200'),
                                                                     ('Match',
                                                                      'ABCDEFG'),
                                                                     ('Seq',
                                                                      '12345')]))]))]))]))])
```

Note: I added an extra `Variant` instance to demonstrate populating 3 instances even though there are only 2 values specified in `properties_dict`